# Android passing Bundle with primitive and Parcelable

Tags: android

I don't understand why I cannot `Bundle` both a Parcelable object and a primitive in the same `Bundle`. See below.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("num", 4); // I like 4.
bundle.putParcelable("myObject", myObject);
Intent localIntent = new Intent(SendingClass.this, ReceivingClass.class);
localIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(localIntent);
```

And my `ReceivingClass`' `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`, (which i'm aware that the sIS is null here)...

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
int num = bundle.getInt("num");
MyObject myObject = (MyObject) bundle.getParcelable("myObject");
```

I would have expected both num and myObject to contain something, however, `myObject` is populated, but num is always 0.

If I remove the putParcelable and `getParcelable` lines however, "num" is then correctly populated (with 4).

Looking at the bundle, it seems to only populate with a `Parcelable` object if it has one, and "drops" all other primitives. Why is this? I haven't been able to find documentation saying Bundles cannot contain both primitives and `Parcelables`, what gives?

P.S. I have tried to add both the primitive to the `Bundle` first, and after the `Parcelable`, but no dice either way.

Comment: your "myObject" key has a problem,you write it in "MyObject" but the right key is "myObject",please correct it and have a test.

Comment: As UperOne suggests, the keys are case-sensitive. You put it as "myObject" but you're trying to retrieve it as "MyObject".

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo when renaming for readability. The question code has now been changed.

Comment: Further to the above, I haven't been able to recreate this behavior in a SSCCE. I will post what was causing the issue when I find out where the complexity is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected, it was due to an error in my `Parcelable` class.

If your `public void writeToParcel(Parcel paramParcel, int paramInt){` method writes too many things for the "make object from Parcel' method `public ParcelableClass(Parcel paramParcel) {`, you will get strange errors in your log, this is what is causing the issue.

**Make sure the read and write methods have the same number of read/writes, and of the correct data types.**

In my case I was writing 4 objects, (2 Parcelable, 2 primitives), but only reading the 2 Parcelables, and 1 primitive. It just seems strange that some objects made it through ok.

Comment: This is totally right!. I put an `int` value and a `Parcelable` object on a `Bundle` but, when I try to retrieve both values only my `Parcelable` object is retrieved and the `int` value always is 0. Checking my implementation of `writeToParcel` method I noticed I write an attribute of my Custom object only when it has a specific value and, when i write all its attributes no matter what, all works as expected.